# How to plumb a washing machine 30 ft from the waste stack?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, drain-waste-vent

I would like to install a washing machine in my basement, about 30 feet from the main waste stack. The stack is fully accessible and already has a capped 2" port about 8" above the concrete floor.

Can this be done? How do I look up the diameter and slope requirements? Where do I put a vent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/4" per foot of slope is generally considered the minimum slope, so as long as you have a bit over 7" to work with vertically, you should be able to slope the drain over 30' just fine. You'd set up your discharge p-trap, and then vent immediately after that...tying that back to the main vent stack. So you'll end up with two 30' feet runs of pipe (drain + vent).

Obviously, check with local plumbing codes for specifics.

This all assumes you have water hookups in that location. If not, then you'll have to get those over there as well.

Answer (score -4):

here is how you would do it in southern Ontario.  The discharge line on a washing machine requirement is 1.5" pipe.  The required slope is 1" drop in 8ft, but do yourself a favour and make it 1" in 4ft so you should be able to start at your existing 2" hub and go up 7" total for your run over the 30ft.  Your connection should go something like this:

1. Connection nipple for discharge line from washer, best to be vertical (up), but can be horizontal if need be
2. Trap assembly and a cleanout port
3. T-straight (not t-y) fitting with drain horizontal out and vent vertical up
4. Drain line on downhill slope over to stack and into t-y (with the t-y) in the correct orientation (the water wants to always flow down, not up).  you can tie this into your existing hub with a reducing coupling.
5. Vent line on uphill slope over to stack to a new t-straight.  you have to cut the stack t have enough removed from it so that you can insert the new t-straight with a couple of nipples attached. usually around 12" with 3" ABS DWV.  then you slide a fernco (rubber coupling) or MJ style (mechanical/rubber) over the bottom of the original stack pipe and one over the top of the original (use dish soap to lube it up).  then assemble all.  tip - fit it all first, then glue it second.
6. Support all pipes every 4 ft with grapple bar connected to whatever is behind it. if need be, run a 2x4 from floor to ceiling to attach the grapple.

Comment: I am down voting this answer because it is so bloody hard to read without proper formatting. If you can take the time to post a lengthy answer then add the small bit of effort to make it readable and look like it was written in a professional manner.

Comment: oh no.  my answer is being downvoted.  does anyone have a hanky to wipe my tears?

Comment: there, now I have edited my question to make you happy.  Please, if you can take the time to post a lengthy comment about my writing, then add the small bit of effort to please send me a Jamaican fruitcake for Christmas, and wrap it in a professional manner

Comment: No downvote from me since code varies by locality, but the requirement for washing machine discharge is 2" per international plumbing code (section 406).

Comment: Ah, another amateur plumbing expert who thinks that more slope is always better. Codes specify 1/16 to 1/8 inch per foot for some very practical reasons that will come back to bite you and anyone who follows your advice.

Comment: not sure what your issue is, but the code here in Ontario (as it says in my response) is min 1" in 8ft, no max, so both are fully compliant  (section 7.4.8.1).  perhaps you should go have a nap and when you wake up you will be less cranky.  and more aware of the fact that there are more things in heaven and earth than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

Comment: I got stuck at step one. What do you mean by 'horizontal connection nipple'?

Comment: not sure how to add a picture, but this is what it looks like : https://www.amresupply.com/part/6300-1-5-inch-DW-ABS-BUSHING

Comment: you could also do it with any fitting that glues into your run and lets you thread a brass nipple (sized to fit your discharge line) into the adapter

Comment: sorry - then you simply slide the discharge line from the washer over the nipple and secure with a hose clamp.  the biggest advantage of this is its vapour tight so you don' t get the risk of methane seeping out past the j-connection in a traditional dump-in setup

Comment: @personalprivacyadvocate not sure about Canada, but in the US, you don't want a sealed connection between the washer discharge and the washer drain stack (which I assume is what the nipple does). You want to make sure there is an open drain there to prevent siphoning. The methane issue is handled by the p-trap and vent stack. (But maybe canada uses an entirely different venting system to accommodate?)

Comment: I am not sure entirely of the motivation for the connection being that way, but we have had a lot of issues here (due to old city infrastructure)in the last few years with insurers backing away from anything that can lead to flooding.  its now mandatory to put backflow diverters in place in new builds and though this is not a code issue, its SOP everywhere.  I have even heard of one particular insurance company having it in their initial coverage questions (I am assuming if you don't have this type of connection, your rate is substantially higher, like when you have fuses instead of breakers)